# PHP Script to populate MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, testing, dataset, test-data

Is anyone aware of a `script/class` (preferably in PHP) that would parse a given `MySQL table's structure` and then fill it with `x number of rows` of random test data based on the field types?

I have never seen or heard of something like this and thought I would check before writing one myself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are after would be a data generator.

There is one available [here](http://www.generatedata.com/) which i had bookmarked but i haven't got around to trying it yet.