# Test data generators / quickest route to generating solid, non-repetitive, but not-real database sample data?

Tags: database, testing, sample-data

I need to build a quick feasibility test / proof-of-concept of a remote database for a client, that will be populated with mostly-typical Company and People data (names, addresses, etc); 150K records or so.  The sample databases mentioned here were helpful:

[Where can I find sample databases with common formatted data that I can use in multiple database engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/good-databases-with-sample-data)

...but, I'd like to be able to generate sample data like this easily on less-typical datasets as well.  Anyone have any recommendations for off-the-shelf (or off-the-web) solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific need this time (which in this case was mostly "people"), I ended up going with Fake Name Generator's 1 Million fake names CSV file for $25.  Seemed the quickest/easiest route for the volume of data I needed.  Worth checking out if your needs are similar:

http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/

http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server there is a great solution exists: [RedGate SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Data_Generator/). It's not cheap, but makes its job very well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good one off the shelf and so we built one based on some simple concepts.   If you don't find any good answers let me know and I'll share the structure and any files you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to this earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162/php-script-to-populate-mysql-tables).

Not sure what database you are using but hopefully it proves useful. I still haven't used the tool myself but i have heard more good reports when i've passed on the link.